# É possível criar uma aplicação híbrida multiplataforma com PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, apache-cordova, mobile

Com o advento da possibilidade de criação de aplicações mobile para diversas plataformas utilizando PhoneGap, como exemplo, encontrei no próprio site da Adobe PhoneGap a chance de criar um app híbrido, utilizando tanto componentes nativos da plataforma mobile escolhida como componentes Cordova. Fiquei um pouco confuso a respeito de um ponto:

É possível criar uma aplicação híbrida para multiplataformas utilizando o mesmo código gerado?

Segue abaixo a fonte de onde encontrei sobre o assunto:

http://docs.phonegap.com/develop/1-embed-webview/android/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os aplicativos híbridos são parcialmente nativos e parcialmente web apps. Como os nativos, eles devem ser baixados através de um aplicativo de loja (como Google Play do Android e App Store da Apple), ficam armazenados na tela principal do dispositivo e podem aproveitar todas as funcionalidades do dispositivo (câmera, GPS, acelerômetro, gestos etc). Como web apps, eles podem ser baseados em HTML5 e exibidos através de um navegador embutido no aplicativo, tendo parte ou conteúdo total carregado da web.

Você tera um codebase bem parecido de uma forma geral, porém, haverá peculiaridades pra cada plataforma, como por exemplo o código pra UI. O UI no Android é diferente do IOS, dessa forma você terá que separar o codebase de UI, ou assets, se preferir.

O que podemos aproveitar em ambas as versões, é a forma como você vai tratar o dado vindo do seu WS, via Restful, SOAP, RTC, etc. Esse codebase pode ser o mesmo, você vai tratar os dados com o pattern que você escolher e reutilizar esse código em ambas as plataformas de mobile.

Podemos então chegar à conclusão que o código será parcialmente reaproveitado e parcialmente refeito, porém é mais vantajoso que desenvolver nativamente, pois nesse último caso não há reaproveitamento nenhum de código, sendo assim mais lento para desenvolver.